# Connect to Oracle8i from PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle, apache

I am building a web application on a Ubuntu Server 13.10 running Apache and PHP to connect to a RHEL production server on our LAN running Oracle8i (Oracle8i Enterprise Edition Release 8.1.7.4.0).

I have only connected to MySQL in the past so Oracle is a bit of a learning curve PHP wise. I have searched online but have found contradicting articles so looking for some feedback on any prerequisites required to be able to connect PHP to the Oracle server.

For MySQL it was as simple as installing the `php5-mysql` package and using `mysqli_connect(ip,user,password,db);` to connect. Are there PHP packages required for Oracle? Some sites mention a `tsnames.ora` file and others don't, and other sites are aimed towards newer Oracle versions (upgrading Oracle is not an option).

I am basically looking for some quick start tips on how to even get connected to the Oracle server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle uses the `php5-oci8` package to enable the [PHP Oracle connections](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php). It should be just as simple to install that package and get it working.

Here's a [helpful page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PHPOracle) on how to do that within Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need the `php5-oci8` package AND the steps on the Ubuntu website, or just either or? Also if I need both what Instant Client should I use for Oracle8i or would the latest work?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with Ubuntu so I would follow the steps on their site first